# Error Running Anylogic Simulation: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: anylogic

I am working on an AnyLogic simulation model that includes a Aeroplance Seat Allocation. The version of Anylogic I am using is AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.8.1
Build: 8.8.1.202210270952 x64

The simulation builds succesfully, but when I try running it, it shows the following error:

```
>     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ???????_2_a_320_front_single.Simulation
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Here is the list of dependencies in this model
[image]

I need help on this. Thank You!

Comment: pls share details on what dependencies this model has, you can find them in the properties of the model itself (where you set the time unit)

Comment: Mr. Benjamin,

I have edited the main post to your needs. Please check the dependencies in this model

Comment: And when did it stop running? Has it worked before?